# Does JHipster JDL have an 'on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

In MySQL I can set the attribute of a DATETIME field to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is there a way to set this in JHipster JDL?

Answer (score 1):

No, you must add it manually to the Liquibase migration generated by JHipster